# How to have text fields hidden by default on page load until the relevant drop down option has been selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to keep text fields to stay hidden by default when the page is loaded? But, show up when a relevant drop down option is selected. The javascript works to some extent. But, I want to keep the input fields hidden initially.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function toggleMe(val) 
            {
                var designation = document.getElementById('designation');
                var organization = document.getElementById('organization');
                var lavelOne = document.getElementById('lavel-one');
                var lavelTwo = document.getElementById('lavel-two');
                if(val=='Trainee')
                {
                    designation.style.display = "none";
                    organization.style.display = "none";
                    lavelOne.style.display = "none";
                    lavelTwo.style.display = "none";
                }
                else
                {
                    designation.style.display = "block";
                    organization.style.display = "block";
                    lavelOne.style.display = "block";
                    lavelTwo.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
            </script>
    </head>
            
    <body>
         <form>
              <table width="100%" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td><select name="select" onchange="toggleMe(this.value)">
                  <option value="0">Select any one</option>
                  <option value="Trainee">Trainee</option>
                  <option value="Product">Product</option>
                </select></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
                <tr id="lavel-one">
                  <td>Enter Designation</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><input name="designation" type="text" id="designation" /></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="lavel-two">
                  <td>Enter Organization</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><input name="organization" type="text" id="organization" /></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
           </form>
         </body>
```

Comment: _How to keep text fields to stay hidden by default when the page is loaded.._ By using css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide the elements:

```
#designation, #lavel-one, #organization, #lavel-two{
  display: none;
}
```

I think you should also hide the elements when `val=='0'`.

```css
#designation, #lavel-one, #organization, #lavel-two{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function toggleMe(val) 
  {
      var designation = document.getElementById('designation');
      var organization = document.getElementById('organization');
      var lavelOne = document.getElementById('lavel-one');
      var lavelTwo = document.getElementById('lavel-two');
      console.log(val);
      if(val=='Trainee' || val=='0')
      {
          designation.style.display = "none";
          organization.style.display = "none";
          lavelOne.style.display = "none";
          lavelTwo.style.display = "none";
      }
      else
      {
          designation.style.display = "block";
          organization.style.display = "block";
          lavelOne.style.display = "block";
          lavelTwo.style.display = "block";
      }
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td><select name="select" onchange="toggleMe(this.value)">
        <option value="0">Select any one</option>
        <option value="Trainee">Trainee</option>
        <option value="Product">Product</option>
      </select></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
      <tr id="lavel-one">
        <td>Enter Designation</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="designation" type="text" id="designation" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="lavel-two">
        <td>Enter Organization</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="organization" type="text" id="organization" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

  </table>
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This stills show if users select "select any one". Could be in JS a `|| val=='Select any one' ` too with the trainee check. Is not exactly asked in the question, but makes sense to me tho

Comment: @JorgeKunrath, you are right but the condition should be ``val=='0'``, thanks for the point, updated the answer:)